# Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b1Vy.png)[This is the images of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEDPn.png)I got the following error when trying to write data to google spreadsheet:

> Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead. 359

Not sure what it means. Can someone help me?
I am following the script from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfhvNHY55cQ&t=596s

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Link](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/issues/171) it seems you writing before breaking line so it will not allow you until the other function is done.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are adding a string that is null (empty). The API for sheets parses this as an attempt to delete and tells you to use delete endpoint instead.

You need to have data in the rows

Comment: Do you mean I insert empty rows to the google sheets? But i already created data in the script to be inserted in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've found way to solve the problem. Change all the headers of the column in spreadsheet to lowercase. 
Thanks for all the responses.